# Cannot apply custom function duet to 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hash

I want to apply a function that way

```
def create_output_column(myDf):
    res = myDf.transpose()    
    return res

df.groupby('id').apply(create_output_column(df))
```

I do not know why I am getting the error

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Of course I know that I can transpose this easier but this is just an example for a more complex function but even in this easy example I get the error. Anyone who can help me here? I know that a dataframe cannot bet hashed but I do not even see where it is getting hashed.

Comment: `.apply` takes a function as an argument, and you are passing a dataframe (a result of the function). Also, functions passed to `apply` take `pd.Series`, not a dataframe.  I'm not sure what is the typo here, but can you explain what is expected to happen here?

Comment: that is right, I undestand it. But if I leave the argument out (the myDf) I get create_output_column() missing 1 required positional argument: 'myDf'. So how to pass the argument in then? The thing is that I want to apply the function to all the grouped dataframes. So I have 10 Ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': [1, 2, 1], 'col2': [3, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Sample DataFrame

```
    id  col2
0   1   3
1   2   4
2   1   5
```

GroupBy (I applied minimum to group)

```
df2 = df.groupby('id')['id','col2'].min()
df2
```

Intermediate Data

```
   id   col2
id      
1   1   3
2   2   4
```

Apply custom Function

```
df = create_output_column(df2)
df
```

Result:

```
id      1   2
_______________
id      1   2
col2    3   4
```